# Do I need TortoiseGit with RubyMine?

Tags: git, rubymine, tortoisegit

I'm fairly new to RubyMine, and completely new to Git (or any VCS).

I want to experiment with Git on my own laptop. Can I do everything from the RM VCS menu?

Or do I need to use TortoiseGit as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. The longer answer is that it depends on your workflow and what you are most comfortable with.
TortoiseGit is a GUI interface to the command-line Git program. When TortoiseGit is installed the command-line Git program will also be installed. This means that both options are available. You can use the command-line or the GUI interface to manage your repositories. If you have used other Tortoise applications in the past such as [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) or [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) then you might be more comfortable performing source control operations through the Windows explorer interface outside of your IDE.

Personally I use TortoiseGit because it felt like a natural progression from TortoiseSVN but I made sure to learn and try out the equivalent command-line commands to make sure I was proficient in both.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, I use rubymine and I only use the command line git with it, cause I am more comfortable with command line git, and a small diff tool like meld, tortoisegit is a separate git tool, If you don't like to use rubymine's built in git functions nor command line.